# Running Time of Algorithms Hackkerrank insertion sort problem

Tags: javascript, time, insertion-sort

The task is to output  the number of shifts it takes to sort the array.
my code :

```js
function runningTime(arr) {
    var count=0;
    var temp;
    for(var i=1 ; i<arr.length; i++){
        for(var j=0 ; j<i; j++){
            if(arr[j]>arr[i]){
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;

}

console.log(runningTime([4, 4, 3, 4]));
```

it doesnt pass this sample test : 4 4 3 4 .
expected output is 2 and mine returns 1 , 
why it should return 2 ? and where i am wrong?

here is the link of the problem : [insertion sort hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/runningtime/problem)

Comment: That looks like a bubble sort, not an insertion sort.

Comment: Ah.  Your comparison is wrong. You need to compare `arr[j]` with `arr[j+1]`, not `arr[i]`.

Comment: yeah,thanks. got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not insertion sort.
Insertion Sort idea is to try to search j that is the last position before i and not less than i and swap them. Every value is greater than i is a once shift.
Try this.

```
function runningTime(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    var temp;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let pos = i;
        for (var j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (arr[j] > arr[i]) {
            pos = j;
            count++;
        }
        }
        var temp = arr[pos];
        arr[pos] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
    return count;
}
```